# Reusable generic CRUD and query conventions and libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm wondering if there are any drop-in client-side and server-side scripts that would allow one to simply invoke methods for CRUD (create, read, update, delete) and query operations as needed for a custom UI--using not only generic REST principles but also a reusable, generic query string vocabulary with reusable code libraries handling the Ajax calls on the client and saving to a file store or database on the server.

The only custom coding I'd expect to be necessary would be to attach events to one's UI in order to invoke those methods, and to check for level of access control in a server-side script when they were called. Everything else should be reusable.

My specific interest now is to create and update arbitrary JSON documents though I'd be interested to learn about any other more generic systems as well.

I'm familiar with OData (but that seems complex, ugly/outmoded in using XML, and apparently oriented for tabular data) and GData (though it appears that may be out the door).

As far as generic RESTful query operations, I know of RQL (but that seems oriented for tabular data) and my own embryonic [HTTPQuery](https://github.com/brettz9/httpquery).

Are there any other generic conventions along the above lines, preferably already with supporting client-side JavaScript + Node.js code libraries?